# Group into group and count using aggregation framework in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I am trying to group data within group with the count.

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("59899846b5f5670840040b0b"),
        "client_id" : "merlin",
        "scope" : "eee",
        "user_id" : "u",
        "user_directory" : "kmdkcn",
        "createdAt" : ISODate("2017-08-08T10:53:58.816Z"),
        "open_url" : null,
        "__v" : 0
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("59899849b5f5670840040b0c"),
        "client_id" : "merlin",
        "scope" : "eee",
        "user_id" : "u",
        "user_directory" : "kmdkcn",
        "createdAt" : ISODate("2017-08-08T10:54:01.908Z"),
        "open_url" : null,
        "__v" : 0
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5989984db5f5670840040b0d"),
        "client_id" : "merlin",
        "scope" : "eee",
        "user_id" : "y",
        "user_directory" : "kmdkcn",
        "createdAt" : ISODate("2017-08-08T10:54:05.280Z"),
        "open_url" : null,
        "__v" : 0
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5989adb2d699bd211caa07ad"),
        "client_id" : "symphony",
        "scope" : "eee",
        "user_id" : "q",
        "user_directory" : "kmdkcn",
        "createdAt" : ISODate("2017-08-08T12:25:22.518Z"),
        "open_url" : null,
        "__v" : 0
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5989adb8d699bd211caa07ae"),
        "client_id" : "symphony",
        "scope" : "eee",
        "user_id" : "w",
        "user_directory" : "kmdkcn",
        "createdAt" : ISODate("2017-08-08T12:25:28.954Z"),
        "open_url" : null,
        "__v" : 0
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5989adbcd699bd211caa07af"),
        "client_id" : "symphony",
        "scope" : "eee",
        "user_id" : "q",
        "user_directory" : "kmdkcn",
        "createdAt" : ISODate("2017-08-08T12:25:32.753Z"),
        "open_url" : null,
        "__v" : 0
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5989adc0d699bd211caa07b0"),
        "client_id" : "symphony",
        "scope" : "eee",
        "user_id" : "r",
        "user_directory" : "kmdkcn",
        "createdAt" : ISODate("2017-08-08T12:25:36.176Z"),
        "open_url" : null,
        "__v" : 0
}
```

What i want is to group data on the basis of client_id and further on the basis of user_id to get the count of documents.

i have tried this:-

```
Logger.aggregate([
    { "$group": {
        "_id":  {client: "$client_id"},
        "count": { "$sum": 1 }
    }}
])
```

I am getting:-
client: merlin
count: 3,
client: symphony,
count: 4

But how to group this on the basis of user_id.

I want the final output would be:-

client: merlin,
count: 2,
client: symphony,
count: 3

Comment: Do you mean *"each client for each user"?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the query.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$group": {
        "_id":  {client: "$client_id" },
        "clientIdCount": { "$sum": 1 },
        "userids" : {"$addToSet" : "$user_id"}
    }
    },
    { "$project" : {"_id.client" : 1, "clientIdCount" : 1, numberOfUsers : {$size : "$userids"} }
    }
]);
```

**Output:-**

If you don't want `clientIdCount` in the output, just change the value from 1 to 0 present next to `clientIdCount`.

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : {
        "client" : "symphony"
    },
    "clientIdCount" : 4,
    "numberOfUsers" : 3
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : {
        "client" : "merlin"
    },
    "clientIdCount" : 3,
    "numberOfUsers" : 2
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Notionquest.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly this your db query

```
 db.Logger.aggregate([
       { 
           $group : { 
                 _id : "$client_id", user : { $push: "$user_id" },
                 count: { $sum: 1 }
                    }
       }
  ])
```